# How do I get Tasks and the UserStory attached to it?

Tags: java, rally

I am developing an Rally Android App.I need the following data.
1.UserStory
2.Task
3.Actual
4.Estimate

What I have tried so far:

```
        QueryRequest userstory = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
        userstory.setFetch(new Fetch((new String[] {"Name", "FormattedID","Tasks"})));
        QueryResponse responseus = restApi.query(userstory);

        for(JsonElement element : responseus.getResults())
       {
        System.out.println(element);
       }
```

When I get the list of userstory I want the tasks attached to it.
Can anyone guide me how do I get the above data??Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't hydrate collection details in the same request- that is you can't load the Tasks collection when you're querying for stories.  However Story has rollup fields for all the task estimate/actual data that you can probably use.  The other option is to query for Tasks directly.  If you can shed some more light on what exactly you're trying to do we can probably help you more...